# What are the differences between Dakini and Yogini?

Tags: tantra

As far as I know, Yoginis are Devi's attendants. I have no clear idea about Dakinis. On many occasions, Dakinis and Yoginis are mentioned together. What are the differences between these two creatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dakinis are female spirits attending to major goddesses. Yoginis could be women with yogic powers or could be goddesses.

**ḍākinī**

> Ḍākinīs are—according to the tantras, texts of the Mother cult—a class
> of female spirits attending on the major goddesses in their fierce
> aspect, like Kālī. Their function is to assume terrible forms to
> instil fear in the hearts of people who are inimical to the devotees.
> They can also be benevolent spirits and guide the devotees, along the
> right path.
>
> These ḍākinīs are supposed to have burst forth from the derisive
> laughter of Śivadūtī (an aspect of Durgā) and fought with the rākṣasas
> or the demons in the armies of the demon king Ruru.
>
> A ḍākinī is shown as a goddess seated on a lotus pedestal with sixteen
> petals. She has four hands holding triśūla (trident), pātra (vessel),
> khaṭvāṅga (magical wand) and carma (shield). The vessel is filled with
> pudding if she is pictured as a benevolent goddess or with blood, if
> malevolent.
>
> Sometimes they are described as the guardian deities of dharma, and of
> their devotees, akin to the angels in Christian belief.

**A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**

yoginīs (‘women with yogic powers,’ ‘goddesses’)

> In the tāntrik practices, the male sādhaka, called a yogi, needs the
> help of a mate in certain occult rites. Such women, ceremonially
> infilled with great powers, are designated as yoginīs.
>
> The word is also used to indicate the goddesses emanating out of the
> effulgence of Ādiśakti or the Primeval Goddess. Their number may be 8
> or 62 or 64. Their names have been mentioned in some of the purāṇas
> and other works like the Bṛhan-nandikeśvarapurāṇa, Skandapurāṇa and
> the Mantramahodadhi.
>
> A few of these names may be mentioned here: Nārāyaṇī, Śākambharī,
> Bhīmā, Caṇḍaghaṇṭā, Bhadrakālī, Kṛṣṇa-piṅgalā, Jalodarī, Śākinī,
> Kuleśī, Nakulī, Ḍākinī and Hākinī.
>
> During worship, sometimes, a group of eight yoginīs is selected. They
> are: Maṅgalā, Piṅgalā, Dhanyā, Bhrāmarī, Bhadrikā, Ulkā, Siddhā,
> Saṅkaṭā.
>
> According to another view, the yoginīs are divinities associated with
> the eight vargas or groups of letters of the alphabets such as
> a-varga, ka-varga and ca-varga.

**A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**

Comment: The list of Yoginis you mentioned also includes Dakini. So Dakinis are also a specific kind of Yogini. Right?

Comment: Dakini is also a specific kind of yogini when yogini indicates a goddess.